# Методы шифрования данных

Tags: java, android

Как можно зашифровать данные для последующего сохранения. Какой-нибудь не сложный алгоритм и не очень большой.

Comment: `SharedPreferences` не имеют собственных методов шифрования, поэтому не важно, куда вы потом положите зашифрованные данные: в преференсы, БД, файл, на сервер или еще куда - важен сам алгоритм. Я позволил себе изменить заголовок

Comment: @ pavlofff да, я видел, спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Создайте класс с таким содержимым и используйте `encrypt/decrypt`:

```
private final static String SEED = "4aab2b7d9bb3dfed9c1617f9a7b2efa8";
private final static int KEY_SIZE = 256;
private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";

public static String encrypt(String cleartext) throws Exception {
    byte[] rawKey = SEED.getBytes();
    byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
    return toHex(result);
}

public static String decrypt(String encrypted) throws Exception {
    byte[] rawKey = SEED.getBytes();
    byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
    byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
    return new String(result);
}

private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
    return encrypted;
}

private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
    return decrypted;
}

public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
    int len = hexString.length() / 2;
    byte[] result = new byte[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2), 16).byteValue();
    }
    return result;
}

public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
    if (buf == null) {
        return "";
    }
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2 * buf.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        appendHex(result, buf[i]);
    }
    return result.toString();
}

private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
    sb.append(HEX.charAt((b >> 4) & 0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b & 0x0f));
}
```

Также следует изменить `SEED` - он состоит из 32 случайных 16-ричных значений.